# What should the generator return if it is used in a multi-input/output Keras model built with functional API?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, generator, recurrent-neural-network

Following [this article](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html), I'm trying to implement a generative RNN. In the mentioned article, the training and validation data are passed as fully loaded `np.array`s. But I'm trying to use the `model.fit_generator` method and provide a generator instead.

I know that if it was a straightforward model, the generator should return:

```
def generator():
    ...
    yield (samples, targets)
```

But this is a generative model which means there are two models involved:

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
x = Embedding(num_encoder_tokens, embedding_dim)(encoder_inputs)
x.set_weights([embedding_matrix])
x.trainable = False
x, state_h, state_c = LSTM(embedding_dim, return_state=True)(x)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
x = Embedding(num_decoder_tokens, embedding_dim)(decoder_inputs)
x.set_weights([embedding_matrix])
x.trainable = False
x = LSTM(embedding_dim, return_sequences=True)(x, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_outputs = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2)
```

As mentioned before, I'm trying to use a generator:

```
model.fit_generator(generator(),
                   steps_per_epoch=500,
                   epochs=20,
                   validation_data=generator(),
                   validation_steps=val_steps)
```

But what should the `generator()` return? I'm a little confused since there are two input collections and one target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your model has two inputs and one output, the generator should return a tuple with two elements where the first element is a **list** containing two arrays, which corresponds to two input layers, and the second element is an array corresponding to output layer:

```
def generator():
    ...
    yield [input_samples1, input_samples2], targets
```

Generally, in a model with `M` inputs and `N` outputs, the generator should return a tuple of two lists where the first one has `M` arrays and the second one has `N` arrays:

```
def generator():
        ...
        yield [in1, in2, ..., inM], [out1, out2, ..., outN]
```

If instead of a Python generator, an instance of `Sequence` class is used to generate data, the format is the same with the only difference that you would use `return` instead of `yield` in the `__getitem__` method.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept this once I get to verify it. Right now, my computer is busy with other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. I just learned that you can also use the "named" layers and a dictionary. It would be great to add that to your answer to make it complete.