# Keras fit_generator: input ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have already tried changing the list to a tuple, from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2568), and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240768/input-shape-error-when-using-keras-functional-api-with-fit-generator), but it wasn't helpful.

The code below is based on [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8078).

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from pandas import concat
from pandas import DataFrame

import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, LSTM, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy

#https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/
def series_to_supervised(data, n_lags=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    #input sequence t-n, ..., t-1
    for i in range(n_lags, 0, -1): #for i in 3 to 0 not including 0
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range (n_vars)]
    #forecast sequence t, t+1, ..., t+n
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i==0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    #put it all together
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    #drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    #print('agg: ', agg)
    return agg

def data_gen(sample_IDs, batch_size, nn, num_features, n_lags, n_vars):

    while True:

        in_1 = np.empty((batch_size, n_vars), dtype=float)
        in_2 = np.empty((batch_size, int(n_vars*num_features)),  dtype=int)

        for count in range(batch_size):
            in_1[count,] = np.arange(n_vars)
            in_2[count,] = np.arange(int(n_vars*num_features))
            count = count + 1

        in_1_s2s = np.asarray(series_to_supervised(in_1, n_lags))

        in_1_data = in_1_s2s[:, :int(n_vars*n_lags)] #expect shape (29, 20*3)
        target = in_1_s2s[:, int(n_vars*n_lags):] #expect shape (29, 20)

        in_1_data = in_1_data.reshape((in_1_data.shape[0], n_lags, n_vars))

        #Replicate in_2 over time.
        in_2 = in_2[n_lags:, :] #to match in_1_data shape; expect shape (29, 100)
        in_2 = np.repeat(in_2, n_lags, axis=0)
        in_2 = in_2.reshape(((batch_size-n_lags), n_lags, n_vars*num_features))

        yield (np.asarray(in_1), np.asarray(in_2), np.asarray(target))

if __name__=='__main__':
    nn = 10
    n_vars = 20
    num_features = 5
    n_lags = 3
    batch_size = 32

    sample_IDs = np.arange(1, 34) #1-32 inclusive and 2-33 inclusive; 2 batches?

    steps_val = int(np.ceil(sample_IDs.shape[0]/batch_size))

    my_gen = data_gen(sample_IDs, batch_size, nn, num_features, n_lags, n_vars)

    #Build a toy model
    adj_input = Input(shape=(n_lags, n_vars))
    feat_input = Input(shape=(n_lags, num_features*n_vars))
    y_input = Input(shape=(n_lags, n_vars))

    concat_1 = keras.layers.concatenate([adj_input, feat_input])
    dense_1 = Dense(4, activation='relu')(concat_1)
    enc_1 = LSTM(4, activation='relu')(dense_1)
    drop_1 = Dropout(0.2)(enc_1)

    y_dense = Dense(4, name='y_dense')(y_input)

    model = Model([adj_input, feat_input, y_input], [drop_1, y_dense])

    print(model.summary())

    #Compile and fit_generator
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss=binary_crossentropy)
    model.fit_generator(my_gen, steps_per_epoch=steps_val, shuffle=False, epochs=2, verbose=2)
```

After printing out the model summary, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Nov26SO.py", line 113, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(my_gen, steps_per_epoch=steps_val, shuffle=False, epochs=2, verbose=2)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1211, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 102, in standardize_input_data
    str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.,
        13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.,
        1...
```

Question: why am I not passing three numpy arrays into the model? I thought the yield statement was yielding three numpy arrays.

EDIT:

This is not the same as the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474497/what-should-the-generator-return-if-it-is-used-in-a-multi-model-functional-api), although I appreciate the pointer. The problem I'm having is that I have three inputs: in_1, in_2, and targets. When I change my `yield` line to be `yield [np.asarray(in_1), np.asarray(in_2), np.asarray(target)]`, I get exactly the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should the generator return if it is used in a multi-model functional API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474497/what-should-the-generator-return-if-it-is-used-in-a-multi-model-functional-api)

Comment: Not a duplicate - I tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and show how did you use that in your code?

Comment: Sure! Please see the edit.

Comment: Please read the answer there carefully: return a **tuple**, with **two elements** where each one is a **list**. You are returning only a list.

Comment: There is a difference between `[a, b], c` and `[a, b, c]`. The former is a **tuple** with two elements (i.e. `[a,b]` and `c`) and the latter is a **list** with three elements. You can also write the former as `([a,b], c)` but the parenthesis are redundant and you can remove them.

Comment: But then...wait, does that mean I need `[a, b], c` even though I have three inputs? No, now it says 'Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays'

Comment: No, that was just an example. According to definition of your model: `Model([adj_input, feat_input, y_input], [drop_1, y_dense])` it has **three inputs** and **two outputs**. So the generator must return a tuple with two elements where each one is a list. Read the general case in the answer I linked to and you would realize what I am saying.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I tried it: yield [np.asarray(in_1)], [np.asarray(in_2), np.asarray(target)], [np.asarray(target), np.asarray(target)] and I still got the same error.

Comment: Nooooo... Am I explaining it that terrible? I don't know... Let's try it one more time: It should be a **tuple of two lists**: `yield [input1, input2, input3], [output1, output2]`. It is not that hard really. You are returning a tuple of three lists... that does not make sense here.

Comment: OH! No, I just can't type :( Now I have a dimension error, but you solved my posted problem. Thank you!